# TypeScript : Referencing multiple Objects of different types extended from a single base type

Tags: typescript, angular, extends, typescript1.7

I am using Angular 2 with TypeScript.

I have a `BaseType` component

```
@Component({})
export class BaseType {
    protected state: string;
    constructor() { }
    setState(state : string) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

I am extending the same to `ComponentOne` and `ComponentTwo` by extending above `BaseType`

**`ComponentOne`**

```
@Component({})
export class ComponentOne extends BaseType {

    constructor() { }
}
```

**`ComponentTwo`**

```
@Component({})
export class ComponentTwo extends BaseType {

    constructor() { }
}
```

I am loading these two components dynamically in another class using following code (partial code)

```
let component: any;

if(/*condition to show component one*/) {
    this.component = ComponentOne;
} else {
    this.component = ComponentTwo;
}

//Load Component
this
    .loader
    .loadIntoLocation(this.component, this.el, 'field')
    .then((res) => {});
```

When I use following later in the same file :

```
this.component.setState("state");
```

It is triggering error

```
TypeError: this.component.setState is not a function(…)
```

What type should I use on `component` (currently it is `any`), or use any casting, so that accessing `setState` method on `this.component` should work without any issues?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the issue.

- I was storing the reference to Component class but not the actual component's instance. So, I can't use the method `setState`.

**What fixed my code :**

Angular 2 returns a promise for `loadIntoLocation` along with a reference to the newly created Component instance.

So, I created another local variable with the type : `ComponentRef` which can be loaded from `angular2/core`.

But this is only a component reference and it doesn't contain actual instance.

`ComponentRef` provides another property with the name `instance` to access it's methods.

**Working Code**

```
let componentRef: ComponentRef;

this
    .loader
    .loadIntoLocation(this.component, this.el, 'field')
    .then((res) => {
        componentRef = res;
        //Here it works
        componentRef.instance.setState("state");
    });
```